# Получение gps координат через Play Services

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-play-services

Необходимо получить координаты местоположения и отобразить их на карте (Google Maps).
Для этого использую класс FusedLocationProviderClient. Его объект инициализирую в методе onCreate()  следующим образом:

```
mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
```

Далее определяю location (вызываю метод identifyCoordinates из переопределенного метода onMapReady(GooglMap)):

```
mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        if (location != null) {
                            setCoordinates(location);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

И передаю его в метод setCoordinates для инициализации координат (приватные поля типа double)

```
public void setCoordinates(Location location) {
    lat = location.getLongitude();
    lon = location.getLatitude();
}
```

Далее в методе onMapReady после успешного определения координат устанавливаю маркер на карте:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    identifyCoordinates();
    mMap = googleMap;
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lon, lat);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Вы здесь"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
}
```

Но, после этого получаю координаты 0.00 и 0.00.
Удалось решить данную проблему следующим образом:

```
mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        if (location != null) {
                            setCoordinates(location);
                            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lon, lat);
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Вы здесь"));
                            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                        }
                    }
                });
```

На карте все корректно отображалось, но этот способ, как мне кажется, несколько безобразен. Подскажите, как я могу еще решить данную проблему?